# How do I make this SQL query work (computed column with nested query)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, nested, case

I want to have a computed column that is true if the field `asofdate` is equal to the maximum `asofdate` in the table, otherwise false. I tried the following but I am getting a syntax error. What is the right way to do this?

```
select 
case asofdate
when select max(asofdate) from sometable then 1
else 0
end 
from sometable
```

Alternatively, is it possible to have a computed column along the lines of

```
case asofdate
when END OF PREVIOUS MONTH then 1
else 0
end
```

Comment: You should specify what kind of SQL engine (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL etc.) you're talking about.

Comment: @r-dub, @rsenna: Sorry folks, SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it in an computed column, since the computed column can be only computed from the values of other columns in the same record.

You can do it in a view, instead:

```
CREATE VIEW
        v_with_last
AS
SELECT  *, CASE asofdate WHEN MAX(asofdate) OVER () THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS the_last
FROM    sometable
```

Unfortunately, you cannot index this view.

Comment: This is helpful, and a possible option. Two questions. 1. What is `OVER`? 2. Are there advantages to this over a computed column (I was able to make it work as a computed column by using this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136197/how-do-i-make-this-sql-query-work-computed-column-with-nested-query/4136267#4136267).

Comment: @Arlen: the subquery in the answer you linked can not be used in a computed column. If you are talking about `DATEADD`, it's the other thing. `OVER` is a marker of a such called window function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Answer (score 3):

From the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx)

> A computed column is computed from an
>   expression that can use other columns
>   in the same table. The expression can
>   be a noncomputed column name,
>   constant, function, and any
>   combination of these connected by one
>   or more operators. **The expression cannot be a subquery.**

So no you can't make a computed column that way.

Comment: This is what I was suspecting. Is there anyway to get the end of the previous month as a scalar so that it can be used in computed column? (The current date is possible as a scalar.)

Comment: You can't get the end of the *previous* month in a scalar because that would make it non-deterministic. You can however get then end of a given month if you can pass it in. e.g. if the signature of the method was `Create Function [dbo].[GetEndOfPreviousMonth](@SomeDate datetime )`

Answer (score 0):

In MS Sql Server

```
SELECT case asofdate 
    WHEN (SELECT MAX(asofdate) FROM sometable) THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 END
FROM sometable
```

EDIT based on comments

To get the end of the previous month -

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(asofdate)),asofdate)
```

Comment: This works in that it produces the right result but is not acceptable as a computed column. Is there any way to do this as a computed column?

Comment: How do you mean? such as select max(date1 - date2) from sometable?

Comment: I mean that if you try `case asofdate when (select(max(asofdate) from sometable) then 1 else 0 end` as a computed column SQL Server is not happy. The message is: "Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed." Basically I need this column to be true if `asofdate` is equal to the max of all `asofdate` in the table. Another way that for my purposes (because of some business rules) is equivalent is if `asofdate` is `>=` the end of the previous month.

Comment: Ah I follow what you're saying now. Short answer is I don't think so. Edit - just saw Conrad's answer :)

Comment: To get the end of the previous month - SELECT  DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(asofdate)),asofdate)

Comment: Glad to be of some help to someone when I'm at the end of a 36 hour stretch of coding. I'm obviously not helping the client :)

Comment: @Kamal: This was helpful and got me exactly where I needed to be. I modified your end of previous month so that it uses the current date, and gives the midnight time: `dateadd(day,(-1),dateadd(month,datediff(month,(0),getdate()),(0)))` and now it is doing exactly what I needed. Basically, I find out the number of months from the epoch to now, add that to the epoch, and subtract a day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this would work, but you could create a computed column with formula as 'MAX(asofdate)', create an index on that column and then create a view that just compares the computed column with asofdate. Maybe not the best possible solution, but might be slightly better than just doing a subquery.

Answer (score -1):

so the maximum value of `asofdate` is stored in a table called `sometable` right? In that case you dont have to check it using a subquery for every record. You can stored it in a variable and then check the current asofdate towards that.

```
declare @maxAsOfDate datetime;

Select @maxAsOfDate = max(asofdate) from sometable;

Select case when asofdate >= @maxAsOfDate then 1 else 0 end from sometable
```

Cheers!

Comment: Is that possible with a computed column?

Comment: Yes, I checked it on MS-SQL 2008 using a test table for a int datatype.

Comment: I don't understand. I tried `declare@KeyCorpLOBmaxDate datetime; select @KeyCorpLOBmaxDate = max(prd_d) from keycorplob; case prd_d when @KeyCorpLOBmaxDate then 1 else 0 end` as the formula for a computed column (in SQL Server Management Studio) and I get the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword `'declare'`.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword `'case'`."

Comment: kindly paste the exact query you are using for testing. It will help in taking off the guess work. Cheers.